# Finding minimum temperature from a kafka json in spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka

I am getting json message from kafka and converting it into key,pair value. This is my kafka producer code.

```
val r = scala.util.Random
      for( a <- 1 to 100){
   var id1=s"ST_${r.nextInt(50)}"
   val date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
   val d = new Date()
   val dateString = date.format(d)
   val date1=date.toString
   val temp=r.nextInt(90)
   val press=r.nextInt(70)
   val hum=r.nextInt(30)
   var first= new data(id1,dateString,temp,press,hum)


 implicit val writes = Json.writes[data]
   val jsonString = Json.toJson(first).toString

   val record = new ProducerRecord(TOPIC, "key", jsonString)

   producer.send(record)
   Thread.sleep(5000)
```

For spark consumer I am using

```
val lines = KafkaUtils.createStream(ssc, "localhost:2181", "spark-streaming-consumer-group", Map("test1" -> 5))
val k=lines.map(_._2)
```

My output is

```
{"id":"ST_44","date":"2018-02-23 23:56:12","temp":76,"pressure":40,"humidity":29})
```

I want to find minimum temperature value along with id from all the 100 stations. How can I do it?

Comment: So I think on consumer side u might need a logic where u wait for all the data to arrive and then u store it on a ds and then u can get the minimum temperature I guess

Comment: Like ur condition to check whether u received all the data from 100 stations will be based on the count of stations whose data has arrived

Comment: Is it Kafka problem or the problem of search maximum value from the container?

Comment: Just cant find way to find maximum value from this.

Comment: Like how can i separate values from above json.